# In my web application, one of the component is slower than other components, how to deal with that?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

Suppose I have a micro-services based architecture. Some of the micro-services are more heavily loaded than others.How I decide how much scaling I do for each of the components? My understanding is I do load testing & find out how much load each of the service can bear & based on that some service I scale say by a factor of 3, some by factor of 5 etc. Now suppose I have a service - payment service - which depends on 3rd party payment gateway which is slow and not in my control - how to deal with that? I am free to containerize the application & user docker/kubernetes.

Comment: If it's an external dependency I doubt we can do much about it. You may need to handle it asynchronously on your side. ? How much slow we are talking here?

Comment: @Imran Arshad, thanks for responding.Actually this is an interview question where I was given this imaginary scenario, I answered that only way we can deal with is to handle the response asynchronously.The interviewer acted unconvinced. May be this answer is correct - I do not know what the interviewer had in mind.Only way to deal I know of is to show a progress bar to the user.In real life I had the payment gateway also in control, so I asked the concerned team to provide more entry points.

Comment: I see. Actually it really depends on the scenario.  Another way is to drop the message in queue and give client message ID that client can poll every X seconds to see if the message is progressed and you don't block the client. Or you  simply drop the message in queue and acknowledge user later via email without blocking the user.

Comment: As this is an interview question a quick one liner solution is Event Driven Architecture. SEDA is something that is coming to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slow 3rd party payment processor can take several seconds to process a request.  This will affect your architecture in various ways.

First, your payment service should not expose an entry point that can take several seconds to respond.

The amount of memory and some other kinds of resources that a service consumes is proportional to the number of simultaneous requests, which is proportional to the response time.   If your slow service can multiply the response times of *all* upstream services by 10 or 100 times, then it can multiply the consumption of those resources by the same factor, and that is unacceptable.  It is also unacceptable to leave everybody waiting for several seconds with no status feedback.

So, instead of a "processPayment" entry point, you will need:

- A "startPayment" entry point that quickly starts a payment and returns a transaction ID;
- A "checkStatus" entry point that can check the status of a transaction given its ID; and
- Maybe a way to subscribe to transaction status updates.

All of those entry points should be fast.

Furthermore, the spreading of payment processing across multiple requests over several seconds means that you can't really rely on everything staying up for that whole time.  Transactions in progress and their status updates will therefore have to be persisted in durable storage -- some kind of database.  You probably want to do this anyway, since the "start payment" and "check status" requests shouldn't have to end up at the same service instance, and the DB is what communicates the status from one instance to another.

Communication with the 3rd party processor should usually be handled by "worker" processes/threads, because request handling threads are not provisioned for those kinds of response times. If payments are processed with a single request to the 3rd party processor, then it will be important to use asynchronous clients to call that service so you don't have to keep thousands of threads alive simultaneously.  The networking stack on your client machines may also require careful configuration to support that number of simultaneous connections out.

Finally, since money is being processed, it is vitally important to ensure that transactions are not forgotten, to ensure that you can always check their status, and to guard against multiple payments resulting from retries, all the way up to the user interface.  The payment processor will provide enough API to allow you to do this no matter what, but it may require careful design on your part.

To support the required user interface, you will also need an entry point that can check to see if a transaction is already in progress for any particular purpose.